# How to call class element when create runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

I want create runtime input by js, and set class but after create input, i want call by class can't work, why ?

=> HTML Code

```
button type="button" onclick="AddInput()">New Button</button>

<div id="priverw"> </div>
```

=> JS Code

```
function AddInput() {
    var newInp = "<input type='button' class='runtime' value='Run' />";
    $('#priverw').html(newInp);
}
$('.runtime').click(function () {
    alert('ok');
})
```

Comment: whats `#priverw`?

Comment: Try: `$("body").on("click", ".runtime", function(){....})`

Comment: @Titus well done thanks

Answer (score 0):

functions are not self-executed. If you want this being run on document load you do following:

```
function AddInput() {
    var newInp = "<input type='button' class='runtime' value='Run' />";
    $('#priverw').html(newInp);
}

$('.runtime').click(function () {
    alert('ok');
})

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // run the AddInput func
    AddInput()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners are only registered after the DOM element has been created.

```js
function AddInput() {
    var newInp = "<input type='button' class='runtime' value='Run' />";
    $('#priverw').html(newInp);
}
AddInput();
$('.runtime').click(function () {
    alert('ok');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="AddInput()">New Button</button>
<div id="priverw">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function to append the button. And the `.click` listener only initializes the currently available elements only. If you create new element later, It will not add event listener to newly created elements. So you need to add event listener again and again after add new element.

```js
function AddInput() {
    var newInp = "<input type='button' class='runtime' value='Run'/>";
    
    $('#priverw').html(newInp);
    
    $('.runtime').click(function () {
      alert('ok');
    });
    
}


AddInput();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="priverw"></div>
```